# Why the NSMutableArray isn't showed in the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app where a UITableView is populated by a NSMutableArray. The problem is that when I add strings to the Array, it isn't at the TableView. Here's the code:

```
.h

<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
IBOutlet UITableView *table;
NSMutableArray *array;
}

.m

- (void)viewDidLoad{
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSInteger row = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)addObjectsToTheArray{
    NSString *stringA = @"something";
    NSString *stringB = @"moreofsomething" ;
    [array addObject:stringA];
    if (![stringA isEqual: stringB]) {
        stringA = @"somethingtoo"  
        [array addObject: stringB];
        [table beginUpdates];
    }
}
```

Anyone has idea why it doesn't reload the data? I don't know why it doesn't work, and it doesn't give to me any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you invoke `[table reloadData];` somewhere in your code?

Have you set `dataSource` and `delegate` for your `table`?

Comment: No for the first question, yes for the last. What I have to put [tableview reloadData];?

Comment: you need to `reloadData` when you're changing your `dataSource` - a `NSMutableArray` in this case.

Comment: replace `[table beginUpdates];` with `[table reloadData];` and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

You must use

[table reloadData];

to reload table againg.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is empty. Call `[self addObjectsToTheArray];` after you create the array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self addObjectsToTheArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `[ table reloadData ]`? Also, `beginUpdates` must also be paired with `endUpdates` which I don't see here. Use one approach or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a little strange.

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
```

Why not just use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Try putting an NSLog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:`
it will give you more info on whats going on.